# ArcGIS Arcade for WebMap Symbology Issue

Tags: symbology, arcgis-portal, arcade, arcgis-online-webmap

I'm working on some custom symbology logic for a WebMap and no matter how I form the Arcade I can't return the appropriate symbol classes, just a block of all features classified as "Other". The code does work in ArcGIS Pro for that symbology. What am I doing wrong?

```
$feature["G2_ERLST_STRT_FY"];
$feature["G2_FUNDING_TYPE"];
$feature.PHASE;

var type = $feature["G2_FUNDING_TYPE"];
var phase = $feature.PHASE;
var eStart = Date($feature["G2_ERLST_STRT_FY"], 1, 1);
var diff = DateDiff(eStart,Today(), "years");
var symbolClass = ["0-5 YEARS", "6-15 YEARS", "16+ YEARS"]

if ((type != "Line Item" && diff <=5)||(type == "Line Item" && phase == "0-5 YEARS")){
    return symbolClass[0];
} 
    else if ((type != "Line Item" && (diff >= 6 && difft <= 15))||(type == "Line Item" && phase == "6-15 YEARS")) {
    return symbolClass[1];
} 
    else if ((type != "Line Item" && diff >= 16)||(type == "Line Item" && phase == "16+ YEARS")) {
    return symbolClass[2];
} 

;
```